# Characteristic polynomials determine semisimple representation: possible counterexample

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

Let $G$ be *any* group and $k$ be *any* field. While studying representation theory, I saw some theorems which are special cases of the following theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem. }$ Let $\rho_1,\rho_2:G\to \text{GL}_n(k)$ be two semisimple representations of $G$ over $k$. If characteristic polynomial of $\rho_1(g)$ and $\rho_2(g)$ are the same for all $g\in G$, then $\rho_1\simeq \rho_2$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Is this theorem true?

Since I couldn't find proof of this theorem with full generality, I tried to prove it myself. After a bit of work, I could prove the theorem if $G$ is finite or $k$ is perfect, and I posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4443467/165177). Now I wonder whether this theorem is true or false if $G$ is infinite and $k$ is imperfect. I suspect there is a counterexample since an important lemma in my proof (Theorem 4 of the link) is no longer true. However, I cannot find any counterexample yet.

Comment: The theorem you state is false for every field $k$. Do you want to assume that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are semisimple?

Comment: Oh, that is a BIG typo... thank you. I fixed it!

Comment: See question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6560/version-of-brauer-nesbitt-for-summands) for short proof. Previously [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407178/reference-for-the-brauer-nesbitt-theorem), refers to Section 5.2, Theorem 5.10 in this [MSc thesis](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/eggermontmaster.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I saw the second question before, but the link to the thesis in that question was broken, so I ignored it...

 I think the most important thing I missed is that for any semisimple $A$-module $M$, the image of $A$ in $\text{End}_k(M)$ is a semisimple algebra. This makes many things a lot simpler, in both approach. Anyway, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer so this is not unanswered.

The theorem is true, more generally for finite-dimensional semisimple representations of any $k$-algebra $A$. Short proof is given in an answer by David Speyer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6560/version-of-brauer-nesbitt-for-summands).

The key observation is that you can reduce to the case where $A$ is a finite-dimensional semisimple $k$-algebra.